# Set Selected value in multiple option using Php mysql

Tags: php

> i have this code for set the selected value in select multiple in my $imeitransferserial this is the value array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "869434022236534" [1]=> string(15) "869434022351051" } in my $imeiserial i have array(21) { [0]=> string(15) "869434022236534" [1]=> string(16) " 869434022353453" [2]=> string(16) " 869434022351051" [3]=> string(16) " 869434022234414" [4]=> string(16) " 869434022342456" and so on.. i just want the value of imeitransferserial will be automatically selected in my option multiple i tried this code but all item is being selected .

```
 $trans=mysqli_query($link,"select * from transferinventory where ITEM_CODE_MX='OPP01-A11WGRY'");
    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($trans))
    {

     $imeitransfer=$row2["IMEI_MX"];
    $imeitransferserial = explode(',', $imeitransfer);
    var_dump($imeitransferserial);

    }
    $query=mysqli_query($link,"select * from inventory where ITEM_CODE_MX='OPP01-A11WGRY' AND BRANCH_CODE_MX='AC001'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {

    $imei=$row["IMEI_MX"];
    $imeiserial = explode(',', $imei);

    }
    ?>
    <select id="tags" name='imei[]' style="width:300px;"  class="form-control select2-offscreen" onchange="getCount()" multiple>
    <?php
    foreach($imeiserial as $is){
        $imeicode = trim($is);
     if (in_array($imeicode,$imeitransferserial)) {

          $select = 'selected="selected" ';
          }
         if (!empty($imei)) {
            echo "<option  " . $select . "value='$imeicode'>".$imeicode."</option>";
        }
    }

        ?>

    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set the value of `$select` on the first iteration, and never clear the value when you get a false for

```
if (in_array($imeicode,$imeitransferserial))
```

You need to add an else -

```
if (in_array($imeicode,$imeitransferserial)) {
      $select = 'selected="selected" ';
 }
 else {
       $select = "";
 }
```

Comment: i put that code all of the item is unselected but those 2 item that i want to automatically selected is not selected

Comment: any one can help me ??